# Secure MYSQL Insert multiple row if condition is true

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, transactions

I'm doing a small project where I have tickets that are limited and a user can purchase tickets in multiple quantities and of different types. I need to secure that a transaction will only be inserted if the tickets to be purchased do not exceed the available tickets left for every type.

Is it secure enough to do something like this?

```
$selectAvailableTickets = getTicketAvailability(1,2,3) //Assume that this returns rows of event_id, tickets_available

foreach($selectAvailableTickets as $availableEventTicket){
    foreach($ticketsToPurchase as $purchase){
        if($purchase->event_id == $availableEventTicket->event_id){
            if($purchase->ticket_count > $availableEventTicket){
               $hasExceedingPurchase = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

if($hasExceedingPurchase) //Cancel transaction, otherwise, insert and proceed
```

Is something like this enough to ensure that transactions will only be made if purchase does not exceed available tickets for that specific type of ticket?

I was thinking that if there are multiple users doing transactions at almost the same time, the condition where one user is allowed to insert might be false even if returned as true if another person buys tickets and leaves none for the other person who also made a transaction and just happened to make a faster transaction than another.

Comment: What you are looking for are [transations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction), with [laravels implementation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#database-transactions) and a [more thorough explanation](http://fideloper.com/laravel-database-transactions)

Comment: @milo526 thanks for the suggestion. I think I get the idea. But do I implement the condition outside of the transaction? Like, check the condition before I implement the inserts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To protect your database against these unwanted failures where the selected and inserted information do not match you can request transaction locks. These are a really interesting topic and worth reading more upon! For your implementation what you need to know is that you can request locks and only execute queries if all queries will succeed.

```
DB::transaction(function() {
    //get available ticket count
    $event = Event::where('event_id', $event_id)->lockForUpdate()->get();
    $available_tickets = $event->available;

    if($available_tickets < $tickets_to_purchase){
        //tickets where already sold, throw exception to rollback transaction
        throw new Exception();
        return
    }

    //safely create tickets since we are the only one with the lock
    $ticket = new Ticket()
    $ticket->amount_of_tickets = $tickets_to_purchase;
    $ticket->save();

    $event->available = $available_tickets - $tickets_to_purchase;
    $event->save;
});
```

Here we are using a [pessimistic lock](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#pessimistic-locking), this lock means nobody can read the amount of tickets available for this event except for the person/php instance who acquired the lock until the lock is released. Since we create the tickets and update the available tickets in the same transaction we can be sure that we are the only one able to buy said tickets.

Ofcourse all of the code inside the function can be extended to fetch all the relevant information (with the appropriate locks). Here you could also use your for loop to get the relevant information for all ticket types.

Comment: Thank you so much for this good sir. Now I have one last question. Does locking pose any risk of maybe.. Network timeout? I mean if someone has the lock processes may get slower because processes are queued and what if there is so much in queue?

Anyhow, it's better that it is secure than just having timeouts if their request has waited too long which is unlikely to happen with low user count.

Comment: Yes this does slow down your application for other users but this is as you already say a necessity. That is why you should use transactions only when really necessary and execute as little code in your transaction as necessary.

Comment: I'd rather have it secure and I'll keep it this way until I find maybe a better solution with less performance loss, but that may not happen in the near future as I still have a lot to learn. Thank you so much!